# How to fix: The feature watch recursively is unavailable on the current platform, which is being used to run Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to run a typescript express.js in a docker container. After running the docker I get the following error:

```
> ts-node-dev src/app.ts

Using ts-node version 8.10.1, typescript version 3.9.2
TypeError [ERR_FEATURE_UNAVAILABLE_ON_PLATFORM]: The feature watch recursively is unavailable on the current platform, which is being used to run Node.js
    at Object.watch (fs.js:1441:11)
    at add (/app/node_modules/filewatcher/index.js:74:34)
    at /app/node_modules/filewatcher/index.js:93:5
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:176:5)
```

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

and the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Init master",
  "main": "src/app.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/tsc",
    "start": "ts-node-dev src/app.ts"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://*****@dev.azure.com/********"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "celebrate": "^12.1.1",
    "colors": "^1.4.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "event-dispatch": "^0.4.1",
    "eventemitter3": "^4.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^3.22.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.25.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.13",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "ms": "^2.1.2",
    "pbkdf2": "^3.0.17",
    "redis": "^3.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "status-code-enum": "^1.0.0",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^4.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.1.4",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.1",
    "typedi": "^0.8.0",
    "uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "winston": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.16",
    "@types/node": "^13.13.5",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.0.0-pre.44",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
  }
}
```

**P.S. I have decided to include the fix:**
change the Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine
```

and change the package.json:

```
"start": "ts-node-dev src/app.ts --poll"
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Node v14 introduced a breaking change to the `fs.watch()` API, specifically that the `recursive` option (which has never been supported on Linux) [now raises the `ERR_FEATURE_UNAVAILABLE_ON_PLATFORM` error if used on Linux](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_caveats).

A bug report and fix have been submitted to `filewatcher`: https://github.com/fgnass/filewatcher/pull/6

Until that fix is merged and a new version released, you'll need to stick to NodeJS < v14, or override the `filewatcher` package installed locally to include that patch.

Comment: So I fixed my issue by using the latest node in docked and adding the following parameter to the start,  ts-node-dev src/app.ts —poll

Comment: The latest commit in that repo was made in 2016 :(

Answer (score 14):

It seems this error caused by `node.js` v14, to fix it use this command:

`ts-node-dev --poll src/app.ts`

Or you can use another version of `node.js` rather than version 14